# Python webdriver with a socket connection

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trapped behind a corporate firewall and need to be able to run my webdriver tests. I have an open socks5 tunnel on port 9191 which I can use to browse the internet

I have the following webdriver/chromedriver code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

proxy_string = "ec2-*.*.*.compute-1.amazonaws.com" + ":" + '3128'
socks_proxy_string = "socks5://"+ proxy_string+":9191"

options.add_extension(basedir+"/ProxyAutoAuth.crx")


prox = Proxy()
prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
# prox.http_proxy = proxy_string
prox.http_proxy = socks_proxy_string
prox.socks_proxy = proxy_string
prox.ssl_proxy = socks_proxy_string

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH,desired_capabilities=capabilities, options=options)



driver.get("chrome-extension://ggmdpepbjljkkkdaklfihhngmmgmpggp/options.html")
time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_id("login").send_keys("user")
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("pass")
driver.find_element_by_id("retry").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("retry").send_keys("2")

driver.find_element_by_id("save").click()


driver.get('https://api.ipify.org'):
```

This has been working at home , allowing me to use an amazon ec2 squid proxy with basic auth to run my tests. As you can see I tried to modify the code to use the existing tunnel by changing

```
proxy_string = "ec2-*.*.*.compute-1.amazonaws.com" + ":" + '3128'
```

which was working at home to :

```
socks_proxy_string = "socks5://"+ proxy_string+":9191"
```

but I'm getting a

```
ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

error. How can I direct the requests through the socks5 tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the port is added twice to the socks_proxy_string - so it will end with

```
 ...compute-1.amazonaws.com:3128:8181
```

If you have tunnel on localhost, then socks_proxy_string should be socks5://localhost:9191

Comment: Thanks , I made the changes you suggested. Same error. How does webdriver know to make the requests through the tunnel? This may be an issue of chaining proxies in a specific order?

Comment: Please try checking if your proxy is available - by doing telnet <host> 9191. In corporate environment - is  this a squid proxy similar to what you used on AWS?

Comment: If you are talking about the squid proxy at ...compute-1.amazonaws.com:3128 ,  I know its available because after opening the socks5 tunnel with putty, I can browse through it with chrome after setting the Chrome LAN settings to SOCKS with port 9191.

Comment: it's not the config, it looks like rather a setup issue. So you have an ssh tunnel - port forwarding via putty, then you proxy one more time through squid? Would be good to understand your traffic flow of network packets...